# Prevent deep-linking HLS stream in video element

Tags: html, html5-video, http-live-streaming, deep-linking

I've looking for practical ways to prevent deep-linking of an HLS stream in a  HTML element. I can add a token authorization, where the token expires after a few minutes, but the issue with HLS is that there are sub-playlists that need to be protected to. Someone could easily get the sub-playlist URL and embed that on a different site.

To my knowledge I can't control how the player fetches the sub-playlists or the TS segment chunks.

So does anyone know if this is at all posible, maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AES encryption of the content and then use token authorization on the key file.

Comment: I don't think I can control how the key is obtained in an HTML5 video tag.

Comment: @Brian You can set a cookie based on login or something. And that cookie can be evaluated in your server before returning the AES key.